# How to pass information to an anonymous class in java ?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
{
    String blabla = "blabla";
    Handler connectionStatusHandler = new Handler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            //Do something with blabla;
        }

    };
}
```

Unfortunatly it doesn't work because of the way java handles closures, i can't make blabla final.

So i thought maybe i can do something like this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
{
    String blabla = "blabla";
    Handler connectionStatusHandler = new Handler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            //Do something with localBlabla;
        }

        public String localBlabla;
    };

    connectionStatusHandler.localBlabla = blabla;
}
```

But it doesn't work also because Handler doesn't have a member called `localBlabla`.

Technically I can create a not anonymous class that inherits from Handler and add there the members I want, but before i do that i wonder maybe someone has some trick to solve it and pass non-final data to inner class

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you make `blabla` final? I don't see any reason not to add `final` to the declaration.

Comment: I want him to have reference to the variable, maybe when the handler will be called blabla would change his value to something else.

Comment: You could still copy the current value of `blabla` to a final variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty hack is to use a `final String[]` with only one value. That way the value is still mutable, but you can use it anywhere you need a `final`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
{
    final String[] blabla = new String[] { "blabla" };
    Handler connectionStatusHandler = new Handler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            blabla[0] = "new string value";
        }

    };
    blabla[0] = "i'm still editable";
}
```

This was originally thought up by someone who wanted a wrapper class, similar to a `Reference`, or c++ pointers, but was too lazy to write out the full interface.

I recommend NOT using this in any code you intend to be maintanable. You can come up with much cleaner, clearer options if you write just a bit more boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new class, call it something like `MyConnectionStatusHandler`, and create a public constructor for it to get the message and store it. Then use `new MyConnectionStatusHandler(blabla)` instead of `new Handler(){...}`.

**Edit:**
I have tried doing stuff like this before, and it either doesn't work or becomes a mess. Creating a non-anonymous class is probably your best choice.